Check if a string can be formed out of a defined character set
I'm working with 4 to 8 digit numeral strings, range 0001 to 99999999. Examples are:

0010
877565
90204394

I need to check whether a numeral string can be formed out of a defined set. Think of it as a Scrabble bag of loose characters. The set contains:

2 times 0 (00)
4 times 1 (1111)
3 times 2 (222)
2 times 3 (33)
3 times 4 (444)
5 times 5 (55555)
2 times 6 (66)
5 times 7 (77777)
2 times 8 (88)
2 times 9 (99)

With this defined set of numerals, the string 0010 cannot be formed because it has 1 zero too many: it needs 3 but the set only provides 2. Outcome should be: false.
In contrast, the string 90204394 can be formed because the defined set provides a sufficient number of each numeral. It falls within parameters; desired output: true.
I thought to carry out the check by means of regex because that will return either true or false, which is perfect in this case. I came up with the following:
preg_match('/(0{0,2}1{0,4}2{0,3}3{0,2}4{0,3}5{0,5}6{0,2}7{0,5}8{0,2}9{0,2})/', $string);
Unfortunately I end up with the outcome that every tested string outputs true, even when it clearly cannot be formed; like 08228282 (as it contains one 8 and one 2 too many).
What am I missing here?

Please provide actual variable declarations so that we understand exactly how to set up the solution.  We don't know if you have some wonky bullet list of strings to parse (# times # (##)) or if you have an array or if these whitelisted number are hardcoded.  We need more clarity.  Do you have a coding attempt?

Do you have to do it with a regexp? It seems like the function array_count_values() would be useful.

Kind-of, sort-of related-ish: Regex to limit the instance count of any character in a string This one is very relatable (transferrable from the javascript context): RegEx for matching words only formed with a list of letters This one is relevant: Limit chars occurrences with regex Also relevant: limiting the occurence of one character across a whole regex string

If working with two arrays of single characters, then this answer is applicable: array_diff() with "one-for-one" element removal when there are duplicate array values

It looks like regex is not what you're looking for.
This regex is returning true because it gets the number of ocurrences of each digit sequentially.
For example, in case of the 08228282, at first, it gets the number of occurences of the digit 0, it happens 1 time, which is between 0 and 2 times ( {0,2} ), then it gets the digit 8, which happens only 1 time too and is true for {0,2} occurences. And the verification stops there, nothing else needs to be validated, because everything else can happen 0 times.
Another example: 877565 it only validates the occurences of digit 8.
I think the solution you need is not with regex, since you just need the total occurences of each digit.
You should look forward for splitting the number in parts and count occurences. Try something like this:
function validate($number) {
  //validate total length
  $count = strlen($number);
  if ($count < 4 or $count > 8) {
    return 'False'
  }

  // validate occurences of 0 (0 to 2 occurences)
  $count = substr_count($number, '0');
  if ($count > 2) {
    return 'False'
  }

  // validate occurences of 1
  $count = substr_count($number, '1');
  if ($count > 4) {
    return 'False'
  }

  // validate occurences of other digits
...

  // if nothing gets it, then its valid
  return 'True'
}


This doesn't look like a very D.R.Y. solution for the problem.  You have to repeat the processing code 10 times.

Probably not. I'm not an PHP expert. But it's an easy to read and understand solution. With that you can make any variation. I think this is the simpliest one.

Your coding attempt always returns true because each nominated digit is permitted to exist zero times.  If using a regex pattern, you'll need need something that scans the nominated digits regardless of their order.
I don't understand the format of your whitelisted number counts, but if it's hardcoded like you've posted in your question, you can use full string lookaheads to validate the count of each whitelisted number. Demo
$tests = [
    '0010',
    '877565',
    '90204394',
    '867530999',
    '1234567890',
    '6',
    '555555',
];

$regex = <<<REGEX
/
(?=^(?:[^0]*0){0,2}[^0]*$)
(?=^(?:[^1]*1){0,4}[^1]*$)
(?=^(?:[^2]*2){0,3}[^2]*$)
(?=^(?:[^3]*3){0,2}[^3]*$)
(?=^(?:[^4]*4){0,3}[^4]*$)
(?=^(?:[^5]*5){0,5}[^5]*$)
(?=^(?:[^6]*6){0,2}[^6]*$)
(?=^(?:[^7]*7){0,5}[^7]*$)
(?=^(?:[^8]*8){0,2}[^8]*$)
(?=^(?:[^9]*9){0,2}[^9]*$)
/x
REGEX;

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    printf("%s => %s\n", $test, preg_match($regex, $test) ? 'true' : 'false');
}

Output:
0010 => false
877565 => true
90204394 => true
867530999 => false
1234567890 => true
6 => true
555555 => false


If you are building your regex from an array of numbers and their counts, then you can use:
$numMaxes = [2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2];
$regex = '';
foreach ($numMaxes as $num => $max) {
    $regex .= "(?=^(?:[^$num]*$num){0,$max}[^$num]*$)";
}
$regex = "/$regex/";


Alternatively, you could return false when a number's max is exceeded and invert the boolean result shown in the first snippet. Demo
$numMaxes = [2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2];
foreach ($numMaxes as $num => $max) {
    $subpatterns[] = "(?:[^$num]*$num){" . ($max + 1) . "}";
}
$regex = "/(?=" . implode('|', $subpatterns) . ")/";

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    printf("%s => %s\n", $test, preg_match($regex, $test) ? 'false' : 'true');
}

Or
$numMaxes = [2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2];
$subpatterns = [];
foreach ($numMaxes as $num => $max) {
    $subpatterns[] = "(?=(?:.*$num){" . ($max + 1) . "})";
}
$regex = "/" . implode('|', $subpatterns) . "/";

Or with negated lookaheads for an exceeded count limit:
$numMaxes = [2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2];
$regex = '';
foreach ($numMaxes as $num => $max) {
    $regex .= "(?!(?:.*$num){" . ($max + 1) . "})";
}
$regex = "/^$regex.*$/";

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    printf("%s => %s\n", $test, preg_match($regex, $test) ? 'true' : 'false');
}


This can be performed without regex as well. For each input string, split the string into an array of numbers, count those numbers, filter out the non-violating elements, then check if that result is empty or not. Demo
$tests = [
    '0010',
    '877565',
    '90204394',
    '867530999',
    '1234567890',
    '6',
    '555555',
    '08228282',
];

$numLimits = [2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2];
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($v) => !array_filter(
            array_count_values(str_split($v)),
            fn($count, $num) => $numLimits[$num] < $count,
            ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
        ),
        $tests
    )
);

I guess what I am saying is that there will be many ways to skin this cat.

Test it with a negative lookahead (add one more occurrence of each digit in the assertion):
$pattern = <<<'REGEX'
~\A
 (*nla: (?:[^0]*0){3}  # 2 zeros available, test with 2 + 1 = 3
      | (?:[^1]*1){5}  # 4 ones available, test with 4 + 1 = 5
      | (?:[^2]*2){4}  # etc.
      | (?:[^3]*3){3}
      | (?:[^4]*4){4}
      | (?:[^5]*5){6}
      | (?:[^6]*6){3} 
      | (?:[^7]*7){6}
      | (?:[^8]*8){3}
      | (?:[^9]*9){3}
 )
 [0-9]+
\z~x
REGEX;

demo

Other way with a custom subject string:
Here we build a subject string with the sorted digits of the tested string separated with a dummy character (@ here) from the available digits.
The pattern has only to test if each group of the same digits (captured in group 1) on the left of the dummy character can be found on the right:
$availableDigits = '001111222334445555566777778899';
$tests = ['0010', '877565', '90204394', "That's all Folks!"];
$pattern = '~^(?:((\d)\2*+)(?=[^@]*@.*?\1))*+@~';

foreach($tests as $test) {
    $digits = str_split($test);
    sort($digits);
    $subject = implode('', $digits) . "@$availableDigits";

    echo str_pad($test, 30), ' : ',
         preg_match($pattern, $subject) ? 'true' : 'false', PHP_EOL; 
}

demo

Other way with the build-in function count_chars:
The idea is to use the mode 1 of this function that returns an array with the byte_values of found characters as keys and their frequencies as values. This array is then compared to the reference array $availableDigits.
$keys = range(ord('0'), ord('9'));
$availableDigits = array_combine(
    keys: $keys,
    values: [2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2]
);
$empty = array_fill_keys(keys: $keys, value: 0);

function array_lower(array $reference, array $tested): bool {
    if (count($reference) !== count($tested))
        return false;
        
    foreach($reference as $k => $v) {
        if ($tested[$k] > $v)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$tests = ['0010', '877565', '90204394', "That's all Folks!"];

foreach($tests as $test) {
    $tested = count_chars(string: $test, mode: 1) + $empty;
    $result = array_lower(reference: $availableDigits, tested: $tested);
    
    printf("%-30s : %s\n", $test, var_export($result, true));
}

demo

An empty separator value can be safely omitted from implode() calls.
